# Spring Thymeleaf #lists.contains not working correctly

Tags: spring, spring-security, thymeleaf

My ultimate goal is to populate a dropdown with the roles that the current user does not have.

```
<p th:text="${#bools.listIsTrue(Item.granted_authorities)}"></p>
```

prints out **[true, true, true]**

```
<p th:text="${Item.granted_authorities}"></p>
```

prints out **[Ljava.lang.Object;@63a6ff07**

```
<p th:text="${#lists.toList(Item.granted_authorities)}"></p>
```

prints out **[ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_SUPERADMIN, ROLE_USER]**

```
<div th:with="RoleList=${#lists.toList(activeSessionsItem.granted_authorities)}">
<p th:text="${#lists.contains(RoleList, RoleList[0])}"></p>
</div>
```

prints out **true**

```
<div th:with="RoleList=${#lists.toList(activeSessionsItem.granted_authorities)}">
<p th:text="${#lists.contains(RoleList, 'ROLE_USER')}"></p>
</div>
```

prints out **false**

Comment: I'm guessing your `RoleList` is a list of `GrantedAuthority`s not, `String`s?

Comment: The objects being populated via a SessionRegistry of all users userSettings.setGranted_authorities(((User) principal_item).getAuthorities().toArray());

Comment: Your `RoleList` doesn't contain any strings, so `#lists.contains` will fail. Consder using `<sec:authorize` with `hasRole` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your fast responses. This is not for the current logged in user.

Comment: In that case, consider creating a service to do it for you and use the `@beanName.method(...)` syntax?

Answer (score 0):

```
<select th:with="myAuthoritiesList=${myAuthorities}" >
    <option 
        th:each="r : ${allAuthorities}" 
        th:if="${not #lists.contains(myAuthoritiesList, r)}"
        th:value="${r.authority}" 
        th:text="${r.authority}">
    </option>
</select>




@RequestMapping("/home")
public String home(Model m) {
    GrantedAuthority authAdmin = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADM");
    GrantedAuthority authUser = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USR");

    List<GrantedAuthority> allAuths = new ArrayList<>() ;
    allAuths.add(authAdmin);
    allAuths.add(authUser);
    m.addAttribute("allAuthorities", allAuths);

    List<GrantedAuthority> myAuths = new ArrayList<>() ;
    myAuths.add(authUser);
    m.addAttribute("myAuthorities", myAuths);

    return "home";
}
```

Result : a select with the only choice `ROLE_ADM`

Answer (score 0):

I had to convert the user_roles to a string.

```
<select class="form-control form-big-letters" th:field="*{AllRoles}">
   <option th:each="itemRole, iStat : ${AllRoles}"
   th:if="${not #strings.contains(#strings.toString(#lists.toList(activeSessionsItem.granted_authorities)),#strings.toString(itemRole.role_list_role))}"            th:value="${itemRole.role_list_role}" th:text="${#strings.substringAfter(itemRole.role_list_role,'ROLE_')}">Roles
</option></select>
```

Answer (score -1):

RoleList is a List of GrantedAuthority.

contains() always returns false since a GrantedAuthority Object is never equal to a String.

To populate your dropdown, you can use this code but you need to add `availableAuthorities` in the model before :

```
<select>
    <option 
       th:each="r : ${availableAuthorities}"
       th:value="${r.authority}" 
       th:text="${r.authority}">
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: So in your opinion there is no way to add something like     th:if="${not #lists.contains(myAuthorities, r.authority)}"

Comment: The HTML is simpler with this solution.